# What is the HAMR Scope?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I'm leveling up my guns pretty fast but I still haven't gotten to unlock the HAMR scope.. and thanks to MW3 only saying "is unlocked at level X" I can't see any sort of description or what stats it effects. What exactly is the HAMR scope?

Answer (score 2):

I was confused about how to switch between the reflex sight (red-dot) and the ACOG sight. You have to press your weapon attachment key (normally set to "3"). I hope that helps you. It took me a bit to realize this.

Answer (score 1):

The HAMR Scope is a mix between a Red Dot Sight and an ACOG Sight for SMGs. You can switch back and forth between the 3x Scope and Reflex any time you like.

The difference between the HAMR Scope and Hybrid Sight is the position. The HAMR Scope has a Reflex Sight on top of an 3x Scope. The Hybrid Scope has a moveable 4x Scope with the Reflex Sight.

Comment: This is what it is in real life. Pretty cool.

http://www.leupold.com/hunting-and-shooting/products/scopes/mark-4-hamr/mark-4-4x24mm-hamr/

Comment: working link: http://www.leupold.com/tactical/scopes/mark-4-hamr-riflescopes/